# Social media Login android

Tags: android, authentication

I need to create a application using android that login by facebook or twitter or linkedin. If user already installed one of these application api in mobile i need to go inside without asking user credentials and receive datas from that api. Please help me to acheive that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have integrated Facebook and twitter in exactly the way you are trying to do, note that if user has the apps(facebook, twitter & linkedin ) installed and is logged in, then while accessing that information from other app(your app) user wont be asked for credentials instead a permission window will pop up of the respective app that your app is asking for xyz details, and once user accepts it then your app can access that details as many times as it wants and user wont be bothered again. 
For integration following link might be useful:-
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr

hope this helps.:)